# IP camera streaming error

Tags: c#

I have a Samsung IP camera and I want to stream it in to my c# program, but when I run the program I got  'invalid parameter' error.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { while (true) {     

        string  sourceURL = url; byte[] buffer = new byte[100000];
        int read, total = 0;
        // create HTTP request
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sourceURL);
        req.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "4321");
        // get response
        WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
        // get response stream
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        // read data from stream
        while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, total, 1000)) != 0)
        {
            total += read;
        }

        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

What might be the problem?

Comment: Where is the line that throw the exception exactly?

Comment: Intelligence check: How are we supposed to know WHERE you got the error? Magic? Reading from our coffee cups? Please name the exact line the error occurs.

Comment: We love a good puzzle. Comments like `// create HTTP request` really help us solving your urgent riddle.

Comment: Sorry Not to determine line here is the error line  Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));

Answer (score 1):

You are not building the correct buffer, you are overriding the old buffer with new buffer each time while there is new data, idea to fix it:

```
List<byte> fullData = new List<Byte>();

while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)//also > 0 not == 0 because of it can be -1
{
    fullData.AddRange(new List<Byte>(buffer).GetRange(0, read));//only add the actual data read
}

byte[] dataRead = fullData.ToArray();

Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(dataRead , 0, dataRead.Lenght));
```

Comment: i still get the same error in Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, total));(Parameter is not valid.)

Comment: did you try the code I posted out `Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(new MemoryStream(dataRead , 0, dataRead.Lenght));`?

Comment: yes i did and i got same mistake . Do you have any sample code to stream video from ip camera ?

Comment: Could you get this ip cam screen in to your test application? 188.132.175.170:1024/home/monitoring.cgi i would be very appritiate if you help me in this point othervise iwill be fired :( username :admin pass:4321

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* (since you don't indicate the error) is that the image has gone over 100,000 bytes, which your code doesn't handle at all. I would, instead:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[10 * 1024];
...
using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    // read everything in the stream into ms
    while ((read = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    // rewind and load the bitmap
    ms.Position = 0;
    Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
}
```

Comment: Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(ms); Same error message (Parameter is not valid.) in that line

Comment: im dont know what format is it. I just wanted to get ip camera screen to my app. Do u have any sample code to do it?

Comment: @user885382 if you don't know what the format is, what makes you think you can load it into `Bitmap`? That is like saying "I have a file; load it in Excel!". You need to know the data format. For starters, what is the MIME type? (the content-type header)

Comment: Thanks i did some research about MIME . My type is mjpeg. i didnt still solve the problem

Comment: @user885382 I don't know much about mjpeg (except what I can glean from wikipedia). If, however, we assume that you are getting a frame per request, you might try: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970689.aspx

Comment: Could you get this ip cam screen in to your test application? http://188.132.175.170:1024/home/monitoring.cgi   i would be very appritiate if you help me in this point othervise iwill be fired :( username :admin pass:4321

Answer (score 0):

kinda late answer relative to the time of the question; however, since I'm hunting down similar issues and this has apparently not been answered, I'm adding my two cents...

There are two issues here as I see it:

First:

You don't wanna put the event handler of a button-click into an endless loop. This should probably be a thread of some type so that the event handler can return.

Second:

As mentioned in another comment, your code is expecting the response to be a raw image of some type, and most likely it is not.  Your camera may eventually send MJPG, but that doesn't mean it comes raw.  Sometimes you have to send other commands to the camera and then when you actually start getting the MJPG stream you have to parse it and extract headers prior to sending the portion of the image to some picturebox.  You're probably getting some kind of html response from the camera (as I am) and when you try to pass that data to a method that is expecting the data to be some image format (likely JPEG), then you get the invalid parameter error.

Can't say I know how to solve the problem cause it depends on the camera.  If there is some kind of standard interface for these cameras I'd sure like to know what it is!  Anyway, HTH...